# How to make a sharp 5-pointed astroid in parametric coordinates?

Tags: geometry, parametric, cycloid

A long time ago I discovered the **4-pointed astroid.**[image]

I was able to make it **sharp** by changing the exponent to any odd number greater than 3. It gets sharper and sharper with 5, 7, 9, etc., but I find 5 to be the most aesthetically pleasing. It looks like a nice 4-pointed star.

Now what I want to do is make it a **5-pointed astroid.** I found a formula at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocycloid) and entered it:

[image]

However, it's **not sharp.** I want to give it the same sharpness as I did when improving the plain 4-pointed astroid. I played around with the formula for a long time, but could not get what I want. I tried adding exponents to the s, to each cos/sin, to the whole formula, but never figured it out.

I'm afraid I don't know much about graph transformations in the parametric system. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: A [hypocycloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocycloid) with $n$ cusps on the unit circle is $$x = \frac{n - 1}{n}\cos(\varphi) + \frac{1}{n}\cos\left( (n-1) \varphi \right)$$ $$y = \frac{n - 1}{n}\sin(\varphi) - \frac{1}{n}\sin\left( (n-1) \varphi \right)$$An [astroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid) is a hypocycloid with four cusps, or $n = 4$ above. You can't make it "sharper"; if you do, it's not an astroid/hypocycloid anymore. So, you're after a *similar* parametric shape, right? Does it need to match the hypocycloid exactly at some "sharpness" parameter value?

Comment: @NominalAnimal Eyballing them, the ratio between the max radius and min radius is 2:1 for the astroid and 4:1 for the sharper one. The 5-cusp guy seems to be more like 3:2, so I'd say I'm after something more like a 3:1 sharpness ratio.

Comment: Okay, so I take it only the shape matters. Try $$x(\varphi) = \left( 1 - c \left ( \cos(2.5 \varphi)^2 \right)^s \right) \cos(\varphi)$$ $$y(\varphi) = \left( 1 - c \left( \cos(2.5 \varphi)^2 \right)^s \right) \sin(\varphi)$$ with $c = 0.7$ and $s = 0.15$ for starters. $c$ defines the depth, $s$ controls the roundness. The cusps always reach the unit circle.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Wow thanks! But I had to change the step increments from 0.01 to 0.00001 or else the cusps were getting truncated. I wonder why it "converges" so slowly, for lack of a better term. Also, to my eye, the curves between cusps seem to change direction a lot more abruptly than the "sharp astroid" I found. I will play around with this.