# What is the definition of a cusp of a plane curve and how to find them?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, parametric

I am pretty confused about what the definition of a cusp of a plane curve  is (let's say that the curve admits the parametrization $\gamma(t)=(f(t), g(t))$). On Wikipedia I found two possible definitions: one that says that it is a singular point (that is a point where $\gamma'(t)=0$) satisfying some condition on a directional derivative that I do not understand and one that says that it is a point where the curve is not differentiable.

This confuses me because I was looking at this post [How to make a sharp 5-pointed astroid in parametric coordinates?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2344904/977628)  and from the comments I gather that the following curve $\gamma(\varphi)=(\frac{n - 1}{n}\cos(\varphi) + \frac{1}{n}\cos\left( (n-1) \varphi \right), \frac{n - 1}{n}\sin(\varphi) - \frac{1}{n}\sin\left( (n-1) \varphi \right)$ has $n$ cusps. So I think that cusps are indeed singular points, since this curve is everywhere differentiable. However, what other conditions should I impose for a cusp and how would I show that this particular curve has $n$ cusps?

Comment: Merely saying the curve is not differentiable at the point is totally wrong. $y=|x|$ does not have a cusp at the origin. Nor does $y^2=x^2$. For a cusp, you want the two (local) branches of the curve to have the same tangent line at the singular point (so compute left- and right-hand limits of the derivative). I don't understand your sentence "So I think the cusps are indeed singular points, since this curve is everywhere differentiable." Note that if we take $\gamma(t)=(t^2,t^3)$, the function is differentiable, but the derivative is $0$ at $t=0$; this *is* a cusp point.

Comment: @TedShifrin so, for $\gamma(t)=(t^2, t^3)$ we say that $(0, 0)$ is a cusp point because we have $\gamma'(0)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{t\nearrow 0} \gamma'(t)=\lim\limits_{t\searrow 0} \gamma'(t)$? That sentence of mine refered to the fact that the first definition of saying that it is a point where the curve is not differentiable wouldn't work looking at the example I linked.

Comment: No, both those limits are $0$. You need a more precise statement, and the limits will be *opposites*, not *equal*. ... To the latter point, having a curve be differentiable is different from the particular parametrization being differentiable. You need the parametrization to have nowhere-zero derivative for these to be equivalent.

Comment: @TedShifrin I see, so I should be working with a parametrization whose derivative is nowhere-zero. Is there some general rule that would help me find cusp points from some parametrization? For instance, how should I go about finding the cusp points of the curve I wrote, $\gamma(\varphi)=(\frac{n - 1}{n}\cos(\varphi) + \frac{1}{n}\cos\left( (n-1) \varphi \right), \frac{n - 1}{n}\sin(\varphi) - \frac{1}{n}\sin\left( (n-1) \varphi \right)$ (which I read that is called a hypocycloid)? Sorry if this is really easy and I am missing some obvious things, but I have just started learning these things.

Comment: If you have singular points, there is of course no parametrization whose derivative is nowhere-zero. That's the point. But you need to understand the simple example I gave you before you worry about your complicated one. Draw pictures of the tangent vectors and think about the right formulation. (Hint: Look at *unit* tangent vectors on both sides of $t=0$.)

Comment: @TedShifrin I tried to think about it like you said, but I still don't get it. I think that what you are telling me to do is basically what it says over here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_(singularity), but in the case of your example I have $\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{3}{2}t$, so at the origin the direction of the slope should be $0$ (which seems all right according to the plot), but if I take that directional derivative don't I just obtain $0$? What am I missing?

Comment: Compute the actual velocity vectors, not just slope!

Comment: @TedShifrin sorry if this is really elementary, but in my calculus classes they never showed us how to do such things if we are given a parametric equation, but aren't the velocity vectors just $(0, 0)$? Would you mind writing me exactly how to do this or link some example to me?

Comment: @TedShifrin oh, I am so dumb! I really didn't know what a limiting unit tangent vector is, thank God I looked it up right now (sorry for wasting some of your time). For $t>0$ this unit vector is $\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{4+9t^2}}, \frac{3t}{\sqrt{4+9t^2}}\right)$ and for $t<0$ it is $\left(-\frac{2}{\sqrt{4+9t^2}}, -\frac{3t}{\sqrt{4+9t^2}}\right)$, so the directional derivatives should be in the directions $(1, 0)$ and $(-1, 0)$, right?

Comment: I said ages ago to look at the limiting *unit* tangent vectors. So we have $$\frac{\gamma'(t)}{\|\gamma'(t)\|} = \frac{(2t,3t^2)}{\sqrt{4t^2+9t^4}} = \frac t{|t|}\frac{(1,\frac32t)}{\sqrt{1+\frac94t^2}}.$$ As $t\to 0^+$, this approaches $(1,0)$ and as $t\to 0^-$, it approaches $(-1,0)$. The negative sign is what characterizes a cusp.

Comment: I wouldn't use the language of directional derivatives here, although I realize wiki did. By the definition I use, the directional derivative does not exist.

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you very much for also writing things explicitly (I realize that this is probably something really basic that most likely I should have known, but I wasn't taught). So, for a cusp I basicaly want to obtain two such limiting vectors of opposite signs, right (this apart from the point being a singularity)?

Comment: Yes, precisely. At some point, you might find my differential geometry text (linked free pdf in my profile) of interest, too. If you want to try to assemble your new knowledge (and the computation for your astroid) in an answer, let me know when you do :)

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you very much for your help, I will try to do it tomorrow because now it is getting late where I live.

Comment: @TedShifrin I posted an attempt at the computations below.

Answer (score 5):

I am posting an (attempt at an) answer to my own question on how to find the cusps of that $$\gamma(\varphi)=\left(\frac{n - 1}{n}\cos(\varphi) + \frac{1}{n}\cos\left( (n-1) \varphi \right), \frac{n - 1}{n}\sin(\varphi) - \frac{1}{n}\sin\left( (n-1) \varphi \right)\right)$$ curve.

Firstly, $$\gamma'(\varphi)=\left(-\frac{n-1}{n}\sin(\varphi)-\frac{n-1}{n}\sin((n-1)\varphi), \frac{n-1}{n}\cos(\varphi)-\frac{n-1}{n}\cos((n-1)\varphi)\right),$$ so it is easy to see that $\gamma'(\varphi)=0 \iff \varphi \in \{\frac{2m\pi}{n}|m\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Now, $||\gamma'(\varphi)||=\sqrt{\frac{4(n-1)^2\sin^2\left(\frac{n\varphi}{2}\right)}{n^2}}=\frac{2(n-1)}{n}|\sin\left(\frac{n\varphi}{2}\right)|$ and this shows me that when $\varphi=\frac{2m\pi}{n}$ for some $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ we will have limiting unit tangent vectors of opposite signs, so all these point will be cusps.
Due to the fact that $\gamma$ is periodic of period $2\pi$ (I think this means that the curve is closed), we only have to count $m\in \{0, 1, ..., n-1\}$ and this is why there will be $n$ cusps.
EDIT: I will add some more details now. We have $\frac{\gamma'(\varphi)}{||\gamma'(\varphi)||}=-(\frac{\sin(\frac{n\varphi}{2})\cos(\frac{(n-2)\varphi}{2})}{|\sin(\frac{n\varphi}{2})|}, \frac{-\sin(\frac{n\varphi}{2})\sin(\frac{(n-2)\varphi}{2})}{|\sin(\frac{n\varphi}{2})|})$.
So, now it is clear that for $\varphi \nearrow \frac{2m\pi}{n}$ and $\varphi \searrow \frac{2m\pi}{n}$ we get vectors of opposite sign. If we want to write them down explicitly we should discuss this after $m$'s parity, but I think this is pretty straightforward now.

Comment: I would simplify $\gamma'(\varphi)$ explicitly to make your "this shows me" a bit clearer. In particular, factor out the $\frac{n-1}n$, look at $(-\sin\varphi-\sin(n-1)\varphi,\cos\varphi-\cos(n-1)\varphi)$, and use the standard trig formulas to get $-2\big(\sin(n\varphi/2)\cos(1-\frac n2)\varphi, \sin(n\varphi/2)\sin(1-\frac n2)\varphi\big)$ or whatever is correct. Etc. We need to see the sign change without telepathy. :) But, otherwise, great job.

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you very much for your help! Now I understand what cusps are and how to find them.

Comment: You're welcome. Do a slight revision (I fixed all the missing $\varphi$s), and I'll upvote your answer :)

Comment: @TedShifrin I will start revising it right away :)

Comment: Looks good. The point is that the second factors in both terms are *nonzero*.

Answer (score 0):

At a cusp the radius of curvature is infinite. Its reciprocal, the curvature of curve is zero. This happens in the cases you mentioned.

The curvature locally switches/swaps sign between $ \pm \infty$ .

Recall that at the cusp we have radius of curvature expression in Cartesian coordinates

$$ R=\frac{(x^{'2}+y^{'2})^{3/2}}{xy^{''}- y x^{''}}\to 0 $$

We have at cusp $$ \frac{dy}{dx}=const, R=0 $$

In polar coordinates

$$ R=\frac{{(r^{'2}+  r^{'2})^{3/2}}}{{(r^2+2r^{'2}-r r^{''})}}\to 0 $$

At cusp we have
$$\psi=0, \psi'=0, R=0. $$

[image]

Other familiar examples are a cardioid, a multi cornered star, trochoid or plane cycloid with cusps created when a point on a rolling circle touches the straight line or circle it is rolling upon with no slip. $\psi$ is angle made between the arc and radius vector.